# I am not getting time according to my timezone

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

i live in India and right now the time is 5:14 AM 8-10-2020
but using this time in my project i am getting a different time Oct. 7, 2020, 11:41 p.m.

```
from django.utils.timezone import now  
timeStamp=models.DateTimeField(default=now)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/India' #change this according to your timezone

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

change the country

Answer (score 0):

If you just have a single naive datetime.datetime instance that you want to set the time zone on, then just use the pytz module directly.

```
from pytz import timezone

settings_time_zone = timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE)
last_updated = last_updated.astimezone(settings_time_zone)
```

Comment: settings.TIME_ZONE is giving warning in settings

Answer (score 0):

In settings.py

```
# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Manila' #change this according to your timezone

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```